# Which security frameworks and tools can I use on the iPhone to secure my data?

Tags: iphone, ipad, encryption, ios

Which encryption tools / methods / frameworks does the iOS SDK provide?
Are there third party solutions which I could use in my app?

I'll be using Core Data and would like to encrypt sales details so if someone finds my lost iPhone he/she can't see how much (or how little ;-) ) my company makes.

Comment: This document helped me with understanding encrypting files: [Protecting Data Using On-Disk Encryption](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know, iPhone OS provides some framework about security.
For example, if you want to store a password, an username or other data encrypting them, you can use keychain...

You can find more infos here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html#section=Topics&topic=Security